# Compare two stores in specific products price (Non-parametric model?)

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I have two stores with products and prices, I want to check if there is a systematic difference in product prices between the two online stores?
I chose the Mann Whitney U test but how I can confirm if this is the right test for my question? I was confused between the t.test and Mann Whitney U test.

| product | store | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | store 1 | 20.2 |
| two | store 1 | 30 |
| One | store 2 | 27.2 |
| two | store 2 | 31.2 |

```
wilcox <- wilcox.test(store 1, store 2, alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE, exact = FALSE, correct = TRUE)
```

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want a paired test, essentially looking at the difference in prices between the two stores, for each of the items.  If so, options might include paired t-test, Wilcoxon signed rank test, or sign test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you for the replay, yes there are multiple options of test to do it, but what is the best? Thanks again.

Comment: There is no "best".  They all test different things, and have different assumptions.  For example, the *t* test tests the mean of the differences, but it has assumptions about the distribution of the data.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you.